# Unable to convert shape to topojson using geo2topo

Tags: d3.js, topojson, map-projections

I've read through the command line cartography posts am still puzzled by this.

My shapefiles of regions in BC are here https://github.com/Mbrownshoes/shp_example

to convert and simplify I'm using the following command

```
geo2topo \
  regions=<(shp2json ABMS_RD_polygon.shp) \
  | toposimplify -P 0.1 \
  | topoquantize 1e5 \
  > bc.json
```

When I plot with d3 I'm using this code, which works for other topojson files posted, such as the one in this example (among others)
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5562380/825c2889f93296bcb78e02a1f85a0981554c1ea7
however, I'm not seeing anything plotted. I do see a path when I inspect.

My resulting topojson file has a bbox and well as a transform at the start of the file, and I'm not sure if that is an issue:

```
{"type":"Topology","bbox":[273366.8019999984,359771.84100000095,1870586.801,1735720.873999999],"transform":{"scale":[15.972359713597154,13.759627926279242],"translate":[273366.8019999984,359771.84100000095]}
```

If I  look at my topojson file in maphapper it looks fine.

I'm puzzled by why this isn't working. Here's the d3 code to plot.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

      // const projection = d3.geoAlbers()
      // .rotate([126, -10])
      // .center([7,44])
      // .parallels([50, 58])
      // .scale(1970)
      // .translate([960 / 2, 600 / 2]);

  const path = d3.geoPath()
    // .projection(projection)

d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json,"mx.json")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, mx) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(mx)

  var color = d3.scaleThreshold();

      svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(mx, mx.objects.regions, (a, b) => a !== b))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("d", path); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried converting a few shapefiles to topojson using mapshaper and when I try plotting them in d3, using the code snippet above I don't see anything plotted, though I can see there is a path when I inspect.

Comment: Can you link to a produced topojson and a prj file from the initial shape? This appears to be a projection issue.

Comment: Yes, the prj and produced topojson are here https://github.com/Mbrownshoes/shp_example i figured it was already projected so didn't set one when I plotted..

Comment: I deleted my answer - it is too close to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448594/7106086), though the questions may appear different at first, they are different paths to the same problem. [Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/a13b0d207ae4e4aa84e6990fbd0bff5e) an example using your data and the referenced example (stripped down) and the geoIdentity method referenced in that answer. There is a slightly different option available for you in relation to unprojecting, unproject and then project to a specified projection on the command line rather than the browser.

Comment: I see. So the key to my problem is my data was already projected (which I knew and thought was okay) when I needed to un project it first. I didn't define the projection in d3 as it was already projected it was okay. In [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5562380/825c2889f93296bcb78e02a1f85a0981554c1ea7) example he re-projects the data, so I assume that meant the initial data has no (EPSG = 4326) projection? Is that were I went wrong, I started with projected data, while he did not? Many thanks!!

Comment: Yes, Mike's data starts as unprojected, which he projects with `d3.geoAlbers().parallels([34, 40.5]).rotate([120, 0]).fitExtent([[10, 10], [950, 1090]], d)`. You don't use a projection on the command line  as you use already projected data - but you need to apply some sort of transform on the data ultimately to scale and translate to the svg's dimensions, this is where the geoIdentity comes in. So you can certainly use projected data (as in my [example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/a13b0d207ae4e4aa84e6990fbd0bff5e) with your topojson), but it is hard to mix unprojected data with it.

Comment: What I'm still confused about is that both my and mike's data were projected (mine started as projected, while he projected his), he didn't use geoIdentify when plotting. How did d3 'understand' his projection and not mine, if you see what I'm getting at? It must be setting the projection using d3.geoAlbers which changed the coordinate system in the topojson so be something understandable when plotting.

Comment: His data is projected using a projection that projected to pixel coordinates - the fitExtent method ensures all coordinates are located within the bounding box specified in that method. Your data is projected in a coordinate space measured in meters. Neither of you use a projection in the client - which means coordinates are simply transcribed to pixels. Your coordinates, being in meters, will have values that are up to seven digits long, Mike's coordinates are all with a bbox with a top left corner of [10,10] and a bottom right of [950,1090].

Comment: Both your features are projected - but yours is projected using a typical projection used in GIS for GIS purposes, with a usable unit of meters. Mikes is projected with pixels, intended only for visualization, hence why D3 "understands" his and not yours (both are understood, but your features are drawn well beyond the extent of the svg/canvas). *Also, your features will be upside down where they are drawn as a d3 projection anticipates that svg pixel coordinate y values have 0 at the top, the opposite of geographic convention*

Comment: gottcha, thanks a lot ! Great explanations.